# Tkinter image labels disappearing when new toplevel opened

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pmw

I have a `root` window with the image labels and then i have a `manage` toplevel opening(with the same image and variable inside of a function), when it opens the images in the root is no more there and the image is displayed at the new toplevel only. Could it be cuz im using same variable? i have tried changing variable names but no luck :( Note that im using `Pmw` here for the `Balloon` widget(tooltips) could the issue be related to it, though i dont think so

Here is a code ive reduced maximum:

on the `root` window:

```
# Creating ? icons
q_mark = Image.open('Image/question_mark.png')
q_mark_re = q_mark.resize((15, 15), Image.ANTIALIAS)
q_mark_new = ImageTk.PhotoImage(q_mark_re)

# Making 2 ? icons
q_mark_1 = Label(root, image=q_mark_new)
q_mark_1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(0, 10))
q_mark_2 = Label(root, image=q_mark_new)
q_mark_2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(0, 10))

# Creating a tooltip for each ? icon
nametooltip_1 = Pmw.Balloon(root)
nametooltip_1.bind(q_mark_1, 'Name:\nEnter a valid full name')
nametooltip_2 = Pmw.Balloon(root)
nametooltip_2.bind(q_mark_2, 'Phone Number:\nEnter a phone number less than 11 digits')
```

on the `manage` toplevel:

```
def manage():
    global q_mark_new

    # Defining Login window
    admin = Toplevel(root)
    admin.title('Login')
    admin.focus_force()
.....
    # Creating ? icons
    q_mark = Image.open('Image/question_mark.png')
    q_mark_re = q_mark.resize((15, 15), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    q_mark_new = ImageTk.PhotoImage(q_mark_re)

    # Making 13 ? icons
    q_mark_1 = Label(admin, image=q_mark_new)
    q_mark_2 = Label(admin, image=q_mark_new)
    q_mark_1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(5, 130))
    q_mark_2.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=(5, 130))

    nametooltip_1 = Pmw.Balloon(root)
    nametooltip_2 = Pmw.Balloon(root)
    nametooltip_1.bind(q_mark_1, 'Username:\nEnter the given username')
    nametooltip_2.bind(q_mark_1, 'Password:\nEnter the given correct password')
```

Now i get the image on the `manange` window but not anymore on the `root` window

**Before(notice the q_mark on the side of entry boxes):**

[image]

**After(notice its gone in the `root` window and it came up in the `manage` window:**

[image]

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Try to keep a reference for your image.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: You don't need to recreate the image `q_mark_new` in `manage()`, just use it directly.

Comment: @acw1668 oh wow that did the trick, so foolish here xd, is there an explanation to it?

Comment: Since you used same variable for both the image in root and toplevel, the former image will be garbage collected as there is no variable reference to it.

Comment: @acw1668 oh so bascially wt ever i define in the root(or main part) ill be able to use it in side function inside functions?

Comment: If it is defined in the main block (i.e. not inside class and function), it is in the global scope.  So it can be accessed inside function.  But note that if it is assigned new value using `=` before using it inside a function, a local variable of the same name will be created instead, except it is declared as global using `global` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a name to your original creation of `q_mark` and do not create it again

```
q_mark = Image.open('Image/question_mark.png')
q_mark_re = q_mark.resize((15, 15), Image.ANTIALIAS)
q_mark_new = ImageTk.PhotoImage(q_mark_re, name="qmark")
```

Use the name everywhere you want to use the image

```
def manage():
    #don't need this
    #global q_mark_new

    # Defining Login window
    admin = Toplevel(root)
    admin.title('Login')
    admin.focus_force()
.....
    # Creating ? icons ~ DON'T DO THIS
    #q_mark = Image.open('Image/question_mark.png')
    #q_mark_re = q_mark.resize((15, 15), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    #q_mark_new = ImageTk.PhotoImage(q_mark_re)

    # Making 13 ? icons
    q_mark_1 = Label(admin, image="qmark")
    q_mark_2 = Label(admin, image="qmark")
    q_mark_1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(5, 130))
    q_mark_2.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=(5, 130))

    nametooltip_1 = Pmw.Balloon(root)
    nametooltip_2 = Pmw.Balloon(root)
    nametooltip_1.bind(q_mark_1, 'Username:\nEnter the given username')
    nametooltip_2.bind(q_mark_1, 'Password:\nEnter the given correct password')
```